# Change color-scheme of qtm in R program

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, heatmap, ggmap

I have R program that creates map in shades of green. No matter what I try, i.e. adding `color="red"`, and `tm_fill = "red"` but map stays green.

Cannot find documentation for qtm that explains how to change color.

Please assist.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e.g.,

```
library(tmap)
data(Europe)
qtm(Europe, fill = "economy", fill.palette="-Blues")
qtm(Europe, fill = "economy", fill.palette="-Reds")
```

If you simply enter `?qtm` in the R console, you'll see `fill.palette` in the first example...